# Search for specific row in database and remove matching row in CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm looking to upload a CSV, compare the first column with a database and remove if it matches and output a new CSV.

**Example of CSV:**

```
tel,name,email
07777777777,Harry,harry@gmail.com
07777777788,Paul,paul@gmail.com
```

**Example of database:**

```
tel         name    email
07777777777 Harry   Harry,harry@gmail.com
```

**End result of CSV file:**

```
tel,name,email
07777777788,Paul,paul@gmail.com
```

I found example on here, but tried to amend it. Code so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once('db-config.php');
    
    $input_filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $output_filename = 'output.csv';
    
    $input_file = fopen($input_filename, 'r');
    $output_file = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
    
    $tels = array();
    $query = "SELECT tel FROM people";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tels[] = $row['tels'];
    }
    
    // Read the header
    $headers = fgetcsv($input_file, 10000);
    fputcsv($output_file, $headers);
    
    // Deleted rows counter
    $rows_deleted = 0;
    // Read every row
    while($row = fgetcsv($input_file, 10000) !== FALSE) {
        $tel = $row[$headers['tel']];
        // Do we already have this tel?
        if(isset($tels, $tel)){
            // row skipped - therefore it is deleted
            $rows_deleted++;
            continue;
        }
    
        // Mark this tel as being found
        $tels[$tel]= true;
        // Write it to the output
        fputcsv($output_file, $row);
    }
    
    fclose($input_file);
    fclose($output_file);
        
    // Now we should move output file to input one
    echo "Deleted: " . $rows_deleted;
}
```

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, thanks for the quick reply. I tried that, its now deleted all rows from the CSV file.

Comment: Yes, see answer, I realised there were other things to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$tels` array is a list of telehone numbers so the `isset()` wont work as the array will look like this for example, so replace that with `in_array()`

```
[0] 07777777777
[1] 07777777779
```

Also the `fgetcsv()` returns numeric array of the comman seperated content of a line so the telephone will be `$row[0]`

```
    while( ($row = fgetcsv($input_file, 10000) ) !== FALSE) {
        // change below
        $tel = $row[0];
    
        // Do we already have this tel?
        if(in_array($tel, $tels)){
            // row skipped - therefore it is deleted
            $rows_deleted++;
            continue;
        }

        // this tel does not exist, so write to new csv
        fputcsv($output_file, $row);
    

        // this tel wont exist in the $tels array? 
        // so not sure what you are doing this for ??
        // and of course the array does not look like that the keys are
        // numeric increments

        // Mark this tel as being found
        //$tels[$tel]= true;      
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've just tried running the amended code, it deletes everything apart from the headers, and doesn't even update the deleted counter. I've checked my database, all the rows are correct

Comment: Did you check that the `$tels` array is actually getting loaded?

Comment: I just ran print_r($tels), and this was the output

`Array ( [0] => 07777777777 )`

Comment: Ahh, the fgetcsv was wrong as well, see edit